# Step in a proof that $G:=\langle x,y \mid x^n,y^2, (xy)^2\rangle$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_n$

Tags: group-theory, relations, free-groups, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

I’m reading a proof of the fact that the group given by the presentation $G:=\langle x,y \mid x^n,y^2, (xy)^2\rangle$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_n$. It begins like this:

> Let $G=\langle \bar{x},\bar{y}\rangle$ where $\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$ are the classes
> of the elements $x$, $y$ modulo the relations. Then the relations
> imply that the subgroup $H:=\langle \bar{x}\rangle$, whose cardinal is $\leq n$, is
> normal in $G$.

So far so good. But then I don’t understand the next assertion:

> We have $G/H \subseteq \{H, \bar{y}H\}$ then $|G| \leq 2n$.

My group theory might be a bit rusty right now and I don’t see why $G/H \subseteq \{H, \bar{y}H\}$ and how $|G| \leq 2n$ follows from that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes sorry, that was a typo. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G/H=\langle x,y\mid x^n,y^2, (xy)^2,x\rangle=\langle y\mid y^2\rangle=\{H, \bar yH\}$

and

$|G|=|G/H||H|.$

Answer (score 0):

I am going to elavorate a bit more the answer of @AnneBauval, since you said that your group theory is a bit rusty. We are cosidering
$$G=\langle x,y\ |\ x^n,y^2,(xy)^2\rangle$$
and $H$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by $x$. I do not completely understand what "the relations" that you menstioned are, but I assume that are the cosets of $G/H$. Now, how can we prove that $H$ is normal in $G$? For instance, you can consider the group morphism $\varphi:G\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}:=\langle a\ |\ a^2\rangle$ defined as $\varphi(x)=1$ and $\varphi(y)=a$. It can be easily check that $\varphi$ is a well defined group morphism, and $\ker{(\varphi)}=\langle x\rangle_G=H$, where $\langle x\rangle_G$ denote the subgroup of $G$ generated by $x$. Since $\ker{(\varphi)}\unlhd G$ for all group morphisms, we have that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Now, if we have a presentation of a group $G$ and a presentation of a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ in terms of the generators of $G$, then we can easily obtain a presentation of $G/H$. In particular, let $G=\langle S\ |\ R\rangle$ be a presentation of $G$ and $H=\langle S'\ |\ R'\rangle$ where $S'\subseteq G$, then $G/H\cong\langle S\ |\ R\cup S'\rangle$. If you are interested, this result can be obtained using Tietze transformations.

In our problem, we have a presentation of $G$ and a presentation of $H$ with respect the generators of $G$, that is, $H=\langle x\ |\ x^n\rangle$. Then
$$G/H\cong\langle x,y\ |\ x^n,y^2,(xy^2),x\rangle\cong\langle y\ |\ y^2\rangle,$$
because $x$ banishes. That proves that $G/H=\{H,yH\}$ as cosets classes.

Lastly, by Lagrange's Theorem we have that $G$ is finite, since both $H$ and $[G:H]$ are finite, and furthermore, $|G|=[G:H]|H|=2n$.

I hope this helps you understand better the previous answer. If you have any doubt, do not hesitate to ask me!